# Test Class for Chart Controller

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-controller, visualforce-charting

Below is a Visualforce Chart Controller example directly from the offical documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm

```
public class PieChartController {
public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
    List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jan', 30));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Feb', 15));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Mar', 10));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Apr', 20));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('May', 20));
    data.add(new PieWedgeData('Jun', 5));
    return data;
}

// Wrapper class
public class PieWedgeData {

    public String name { get; set; }
    public Integer data { get; set; }

    public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
}
```

How exactly would you write a test class for this. How do I add data to the chart specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test would just instantiate the class and request the list:

```
@isTest static void test() {
    PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController();
    PieChartController.PieWedgeData[] data = ctrl.getPieData();
    // Verify data contains correct values, via System.assert
}
```

This example uses *hard-coded* data, so there's nothing to add. In the "real world", your getPieData() function would call a query, then generate data from that. Accordingly, if you were using a controller that used such a query, you'd just populate those records in the database via normal insert commands:

```
SObject[] records = new SObject[0];
// populate records
// Afterwards...
insert records;
Test.startTest();
PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController();
PieChartController.PieWedgeData[] data = ctrl.getPieData();
Test.stopTest();
// Verify data contains correct values, via System.assert
```